# How to Find Week Number in look up Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Two Tables
One is Lookup Table **Week** for **WeekNumber** and **Weekdate**

[image]

And Another is **Register**

[image]

What I want to Return is current WeekLabel from the Week table where  Entrytime is falling between two dates

***For example :***

- Entrytime `2016-08-15 09:02:15.0000000`
- is between Weekstartdate value `2016-08-15 00:00:00.000` and `2016-08-22 00:00:00.000`
- so I want to return **WeekLabel** 1 and **WeekStartdate** 2016-08-15 from week table and so on..

Answer (score 3):

Using [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the latest `WeekStartDate` that occurs before or on `EntryTime`.

```
select r.*
  , x.WeekLabel
from register r
  cross apply (
    select top 1 w.WeekLabel
    from [Week] w
    where w.weekstartdate =< r.entrytime
    order by w.weekstartdate desc
    ) as x
```

switch to `outer apply()` for `left join` functionality, e.g. return `null` if there is no corresponding `WeekLabel`.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the tables based on the `entrytime` being greater than the `weekstartdate`; this will multiply each entry for all the preceding weeks, so you can get the latest one with a `max` on `WeekLabel` (assuming they're constantly increasing).

```
select  t2.ID, t2.CODE, max(t1.WeekLabel)
from    Week t1
join    Register t2
on      t2.Entrytime > t1.Weekstartdate
group by t2.ID, t2.CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a simple JOIN

```
Select R.*
      ,W.WeekLabel
      ,W.WeekStartdate 
 From  Register R
 Join  [Week] W
   on  R.EntryTime >= W.WeekStartDate
  and  R.EntryTime <  DateAdd(DAY,7,W.WeekStartDate)
```

Comment: Lovely simple approach, but shouldn't `DATEADD(DAY, 8...` read `DATEADD(DAY, 7...`?  Example:  2016-08-15 + 7 = 2016-08-22.  Both of these were Monday.

Comment: @destination-data corrected ... I was overthinking it  .   Thanks for the catch

Comment: We'll all been there!  Nice approach, that avoids using a correlated subquery or unnecessary aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to join to the week reference table using the `datediff` function:

```
SELECT * from 
register r 
join [Week] w on 
     DATEDIFF(day, r.entryTime, w.weekStartDate) between 0 and 7
```